# How does Charles Xavier pay for all of the gadgets at the X-Mansion?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In mainstream Marvel Comics, how does Charles Xavier pay for all the gadgets at the X-Mansion? I understand that the mansion itself has been in his family, but the Danger Room, Cerebro, the X-Jet, missile defense systems, and all of the advanced technology must cost and arm and a leg, not to mention the electricity and other materials to power them. And unlike Bruce Wayne over at DC Comics, Xavier doesn't have a company generating revenue to pay for it.

How does Charles Xavier pay for all the gadgets at the X-Mansion? Does one of the mutants have the power to print money?

This question was inspired by Atop the Fourth Wall's [review of X-Men #1](http://atopthefourthwall.com/x-men-1/), which jokingly suggested that Xavier got a Pell Grant for the school to fund missile defense systems.

Comment: He's a shady dude who uses his telepathy to manipulate people into giving him shit for free.

Comment: abnormally generous donations of course

Comment: If you can control events telepathically on a global scale, you can make a fortune in the stock market again and again.

Comment: I doubt Xavier is *controlling* anyone (although he's certainly used his powers that way, he's reluctant too, particularly on innocent people and particularly in the comics). However, he might be reading people's minds to get insider information on stocks. More likely, though, there are simply a number of very rich people who value the services he provides: saving the world, preventing young mutants from blowing things up, that sort of thing.